# Wheel alighment still showing red front right camber

Tags: ford, fusion

[image]

It was for a Ford fusion, but it's a 2011 not 2006-09 as shown on the alignment, done at kwikfit yesterday. Front right camber is showing-1°49  from -1°56 should I be concerned, would the adjustment need to be different for a different aged vehicle too?